# SQL Server query with symbol (')

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I make a query to see if any record have the value (')?
I have tried this:
`Select * from table where column LIKE '%'%'` and other variants and still get sintax error.

And i have the same problem when I do a query like:
 `Select * from table where column == 'hello'world'`
I have in the database a record stored with `hello'world`

I guess that bot questions have the same answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to escape it by using the single quote twice (`''`), It will be considered as the single quote rather than the starting/ending of the string as follows:

```
Select * from table where column LIKE '%''%'
```

You can also use the [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> According to documentation, When QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, Literals can
> be delimited by either single or double quotation marks. If a literal
> string is delimited by double quotation marks, the string can contain
> embedded single quotation marks, such as apostrophes.

You can use it as follows:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

Select * from table where column LIKE "%'%"

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
```

Answer (score 2):

`'` has to be doubled:

```
Select * from tab where col LIKE '%''%'
```

Comment: So in the second case would be ```hello''world```?

Comment: @This_place_is_hard_on_newers Yes, exactly